# Parsing double values using Double vs BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I'm an experienced developer but not a math expert. I know enough about the IEEE floating point specification to be afraid of making assumptions about parsing, printing, and comparing them.

I know I can parse a `double` from a `String` using [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-). I know I can also parse that same string into a `BigDecimal` using [`new BigDecimal(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-), and then ask the `BigDecimal` for a `double` using [`BigDecimal.doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue--).

I glanced at the API and code for both techniques, and it seems that `BigDecimal` has a lot of different parsing and conversion options.

Are both techniques (`Double.parseDouble(s)` and `new BigDecimal(s).doubleValue()`) guaranteed, for all string inputs, to produce exactly the same `double` primitive value, provided the value is not outside the range of plus or minus `Double.MAX_DOUBLE`?

Comment: The docs don't say anything about this specifically, so you'd have to look at the source. I'd do it myself, but I'm not at my workstation right now.

Comment: In JDK 13, `BigDecimal#doubleValue` actually invokes `Double#parseDouble` if "the absolute value of the significand of this BigDecimal is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE". This was taken from the javadoc on `BigDecimal`'s `intCompact` field.

Comment: Technically one difference is `new BigDecimal(null).doubleValue()` is a compilation issue, while `Double.parseDouble(null)` is a `NullPointerException`, but still compiles.  This is just if `null` is not cast as a `String` though because `BigDecimal` is overloaded.

Comment: I don't think you will get a guarantee here, but it is very likely. But they use different way to parse the String (`readJavaFormatString#readJavaFormatString(String)` and `BigDecimal(char[], int, int MathContext)`). Although they seem to work similar, they could change in future releases which introduce differences in the results.

Comment: The Javadoc for `Double` is precise about what `double` value you get by calling `parseDouble` on a `String`.  The Javadoc for `BigDecimal` is not precise, so there is no guarantee about what `double` value you get.  I consider this to be an omission in the Javadoc for `BigDecimal`, and I hope Oracle improve it in a future release.

Answer (score 5):

For most input values, both techniques should yield the same values.  While it's still possible they might not, it doesn't seem likely.

The [`BigDecimal(String)` constructor Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) states:

> **API Note:**
>
> For values other than `float` and `double` NaN and ±Infinity, this constructor is compatible with the values returned by `Float.toString(float)` and `Double.toString(double)`.

However, the [`Double.parseDouble(String)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) states:

> Returns a new `double` initialized to the value represented by the specified `String`, as performed by the `valueOf` method of class `Double`.

And that goes on to describe the format accepted by the method.

**Let's Test It!**

Let's test some values.  It looks like an incredibly huge effort to test this exhaustively, but let's test including some string values that represent values known to produce floating-point errors or to be inexact representations.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] values = {"0", "0.1", "0.33333333333333333333", "-0", "-3.14159265", "10.1e100",
            "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000142857142857",
            "10000000000.000000000000000001", "2.718281828459",
            "-1.23456789e-123", "9.87654321e+71", "66666666.66666667",
            "1.7976931348623157E308", "2.2250738585072014E-308", "4.9E-324",
            "3.4028234663852886E38", "1.1754943508222875E-38", "1.401298464324817E-45",
            String.valueOf(Math.E), String.valueOf(Math.PI), String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(2))
    };
    for (String value : values) {
        System.out.println(isDoubleEqual(value));
    }
}
// Test if the representations yield the same exact double value.
public static boolean isDoubleEqual(String s) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s);
    double d2 = new BigDecimal(s).doubleValue();
    return d1 == d2;
}
```

For these values, I get all `true`s.  This is not by any means exhaustive, so it would be very difficult to *prove* it true for all possible `double` values.  All it would take is one `false` to show a counterexample.  However, this seems to be some evidence that it is true for all legal `double` string representations.

I also tried leading spaces, e.g. `"   4"`.  The `BigDecimal(String)` constructor threw a `NumberFormatException` but `Double.parseDouble` trimmed the input correctly.

The `BigDecimal(String)` constructor won't accept `Infinity` or `NaN`, but you only asked about the normal finite range.  The `Double.parseDouble` method accepts hexadecimal floating point representations but `BigDecimal(String)` does not.

If you include these edge cases, one method may throw an exception where the other would not.  If you're looking for normal base-10 strings of finite values within range, the answer is "it seems likely".

Answer (score 5):

> Are both techniques (`Double.parseDouble(s)` and `new BigDecimal(s).doubleValue()`) guaranteed, for all string inputs, to produce exactly the same double primitive value, provided the value is not outside the range of plus or minus `Double.MAX_DOUBLE`?

No, certainly not.

For one thing, there are some string inputs that `Double.parseDouble(s)` supports but `new BigDecimal(s)` does not (for example, hex literals).

For another, `Double.parseDouble("-0")` yields *negative* zero, whereas `new BigDecimal("-0").doubleValue()` yields *positive* zero (because `BigDecimal` doesn't have a concept of signed zero).

And while not directly relevant to your question, I've been asked to point out for the benefit of other readers that `Double.parseDouble(s)` supports NaNs and infinities, whereas `BigDecimal` does not.

Comment: BigDecimal also lacks infinities and NaNs.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Correct; those fall under "string inputs that `Double.parseDouble(s)` supports but `new BigDecimal(s)` does not". Since the OP specified that "the value is not outside the range of plus or minus `Double.MAX_DOUBLE`", I decided it didn't make sense to call those out individually.

Comment: I'm suggesting listing them for future readers. I agree that the limitation stated in the question excludes infinity and NaN.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Very well.